# Is there an easy way to move several files to a directory if they are not in the directory?

Tags: python, unix

I have a lot of jpg files in folder1, and some of those were edited and saved into folder2 with the same name as the original file. Is there an easy way to move all the jpg files from folder1 into folder2 that are not already in folder2?

I was trying to do this using a python script, but now I'm thinking it may be easier with unix commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ca also do

```
mv --no-clobber folder1/*.jpg folder2/
```

or

```
mv -n folder1/*.jpg folder2/
```

to not overwrite files in `folder2`

Answer (score 1):

A simple loop in bash that checks if the file exists before moving it.

```bash
cd folder2
folder1="/path/to/folder1"
for file in *.jpg
do
    if ! [ -e "$folder1/$file" ]
    then mv "$file" "$folder1"
    fi
done
```